# Routing requests to index on Google Storage Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage

In an attempt to host a (static) SPA app on Google Bucket Storage, I am wondering if it is possible at all, considering a typical SPA have dynamic routes.

For example, in a request to a SPA app:

```
www.myapp.com/user/jon
```

You would config the server to route such request to the index.html file,
or else it will throw a 404.

How can I configure Google Bucket to redirect all (even better if I get to specify) requests to the index.html in the bucket?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at setting the `website` metadata attribute in your bucket:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website

Comment: Yes. in the examples listed, i would want 'http://www.example.com/hello The object "404.html". 404' to load 'index.html', not 404.html.